# SQL Text to Minutes

Tags: sql, powerbi

I have this string duration format in a column in SQL: "00:01:52"

So, I want to convert it to minutes int

00:01:52 means: 0 hours, 1 minutes, 52 seconds

In this case it will be 1 min.

How can I make a query to get the data at 'int' variable

Comment: I removed the conflicting tags: mysql <> sql-server <> postgresql - especially when it comes to date/time functions, which are highly vendor-specific. Please tag only the database that you are using.

Comment: What have you tried? SQL Server provides a number of datetime functions.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, you can use:

```
select datediff(minute, 0, convert(time, '00:01:52'))
```

Comment: How can I change '00:01:52' to the column name

to get all the column in the new format

Comment: Algo I would like , to convert it in a format keeping seconds, to add them all the collumn and get total time with seconds in a power bi view


How can I do this?

Comment: @MarcoAMedina. . . You would just put the column name there instead of the constant.